# Bot Hangouts Chat API - Not Working in ROOM

Tags: bots, google-hangouts

I have a simple bot that identify a tag "@Ticket" and send an email.

My Bot in DM works, but when i join the bot into a room, it doesn't work.

Hangouts Chat API functionality - bot works in rooms and bot works in direct messages are enabled

My code is:

```
function onMessage(event) {
    console.info(event);
    var name = "";

    if (event.space.type == "DM") {
        name = "You open:";
    } else {
        name = event.message.sender.displayName + " open:";
    }

    var message = name + event.message.text.toUpperCase() + "\"";

    if (message) {
         if (message.indexOf('@Ticket') > -1) {
            MailApp.sendEmail("email-account", name + "ticket", message);
         }
    }

}


function onAddToSpace(event) {
    console.info(event);
    var message = "";

    if (event.space.type == "DM") {
        message = "Tickets in DM, " + event.user.displayName + "!";
    } else {
       eturn { "text": message }; message = "Tickets add to " + event.space.displayName;
    }            
}

    function onRemoveFromSpace(event) {
        console.info("Tickets removed ", event.space.name);
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75245758

Answer (score 0):

I debug the bot and I noticed that when bot is a member of a room, the sent message does not generate any events.

Event generated in DM

```
jsonPayload: {
      configCompleteRedirectUrl:  
           "https://chat.google.com/api/bot_config_complete?token=XXXXXX"   
      eventTime: {…}   
      message: {
      argumentText:  "@Ticket: Open"    
      createTime: {…}    
      name:  "spaces/XXXXXX/messages/XXX.XXX"    
      sender: {…}    
      space: {…}    
      text:  "@Ticket: Open"    
      thread: {…}
```

Event generated in ROOM

```
  No logs are found
```

In the API references we have event fields:

[Event fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe71d.png)

I don´t know if a bot being a member of a room, can recognize all the events generated in the room (event.message.text) or is it really necessary to click on the bot and start a DM, necessary for the events (event.message. text) are recognized.